# Bulk insert with cx_Oracle: inconsistent data types

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to load a large number of records into an Oracle DB using Python and `cx_Oracle`. The consensus seems to be that you should prepare a cursor and `executemany` against a list of rows (per [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnho6J6_LMAhUjUaYKHZ-uAPcQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F14904033%2Fhow-can-i-do-a-batch-insert-into-an-oracle-database-using-python&usg=AFQjCNGOvdfih-9v1V5TI_2l7c6teqy_qA) post). So my code looks like:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO table (address, shape) VALUES (:1, :2)"
cursor.prepare(stmt)
rows = []
# Make huge list of rows
cursor.executemany(None, rows)
```

The values I'm passing in look like this:

```
['1234 MARKET ST', "SDE.ST_Geometry('POINT (0 0)', 2272)"]
```

The problem is that the `SDE.ST_Geometry()` database function is being treated as a literal string rather than being evaluated, so I get a  `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected SDE.ST_GEOMETRY got CHAR`.

Is it not possible to pass in database functions to a prepared cursor with `cx_Oracle`?

Comment: See if this helps: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124574/bulk-insert-with-python-and-cx-oracle-into-st-geometry-enabled-table

Comment: That led me in the right direction, thanks @PatrickMarchand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got around this by embedding the function call in the prepared statement:

```
stmt = "INSERT INTO table (address, shape) VALUES (:1, ST_Geometry(:2, 2272))"
```

Hat tip to PatrickMarchand for the hint.

Comment: Make sure you define SDE.ST_Geometry for ESRI.

Answer (score 1):

The brief answer is that since you are passing a string, it is treated as a string.  Bind values are only every treated as data.

But look at the not-yet released cx_Oracle main line https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle?  It has new object support.

And look at this commit "Added example for creating SDO_GEOMETRY.":
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle/commits/2672c799d987a8901ac1c4917e87ae4101a1d605